# How can we get the google auth token using DotnetOpenAuth?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, google-reader

I am writing an application in .net which will help users to get their Google Reader subscription lists.

I was thinking of using DotnetOpenAuth for authentication and then get google auth token. The users will enter google credentials on Google site and finally they will be redirected to my application with auth token. Now using this auth token I was planning to make a request to google reader endpoint which returns the subscriptions list as an opml file.

Do anyone has any idea? Please share.

Comment: This is just a gentle comment from a fellow programmer like you. I know that this will not answer your question but if I were you, I will not spend anytime on this as Google Reader will be deactivated soon. http://support.google.com/reader/answer/3028851

Comment: The reason I am doing this is because google reader is going away in few days. I want to get the users subscriptions from google reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a DotNetOpenAuth client for Google that uses OAuth2.  You should be able to use this to get the auth token back.

https://github.com/mj1856/DotNetOpenAuth.GoogleOAuth2

If you use the new `OAuthWebSecurity` classes from [Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages.OAuth/), then you will fine the Google access token returned to you in the results from the `OauthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication` in your callback method.

**UPDATE** - The above answer is specifically with regard to DotNetOpenAuth in MVC4.  MVC5 does not use DotNetOpenAuth, and comes with a Google OAuth solution already.

Comment: To use Google oAuth2 is it mandatory to have client_id, client_secret etc?

Comment: Yes.  You establish an application on Google's [dev console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) to get them.

Comment: Isn't there any other way?

Comment: Of course not.  Why would Google give you an auth token without you being authenticated?

Comment: Actually, I was speaking from an OAuth2 perspective.  If you want to use OpenID instead, you don't have to preregister your application.  But I'm really not sure if they will give you an auth token when you use OpenID or not.  It's not really what that is designed for.

Comment: You are right OpenID do not give auth token because I already tried it.

Comment: I see that you are throwing exception if the requested scope is not provided. Is it mandatory? If not, what are the possible values of it?

Comment: There is a constructor there that supplies some default scopes if you provide none.  I have no idea what all possible scopes are, or if you need to pass specific scopes for Google Reader.  You'll have to dig through documentation.  It looks like most of the Google Reader API is undocumented, or the docs have been removed.  Good luck.

Comment: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. This what I am getting after I changed the scope to http://www.google.com/reader/api. Not much help on this though. Do you have any idea in which case Google will throw this error?

Comment: No. Sorry. I have no idea.